# How to add a modifier to a nested document with mongodb

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have this model

1. This is the model

```
    const PostSchema = nongoose.Schema(
      {
    body: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      maxlength: 250,
      required: true,
    },
    comments: {
      required: true,
      type: [
        {
          creatorId: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
          },
          creator: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
          },
          timestamp: Number,
          body: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            trim: true,
          },
          likes: {
            type: [String],
            required: true,
          },
          replies: {
            require: true,
            type: [
              {
                creatorId: String,
                creatorName: String,
                timestamp: Number,
                body: {
                  type: String,
                },
              },
            ],
          },
        },
      ],
    },
      },
      {
    timestamps: true,
      }
    );
```

I want to append   `isReady= true` to each comments every time I get all the posts.
Basically I do not want to add it to my db.

2. This is my controller

```
module.exports.readPost = async (req, res) => {
  await PostModel.find((err, doc) => {
    !err ? res.send(doc) : console.log("Get Data Error" + err);
  }).sort({ createdAt: -1 });
};
```

I want to append   `isReady= true` to each comments every time I get all the posts.
Basically I do not want to add it to my db.

Comment: By not adding it to your collection, do you mean not saving it to the db?

Comment: yes, i wanna do it from server

Answer (score 0):

Use [Mongoose Lean](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) to convert doc to a javascript object and then use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to modify all the `items` in `docs`

```js
module.exports.readPost = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const doc = await PostModel.find().lean();
    const sortedDoc = doc.sort({ createdAt: -1 });
    const modifiedDocs = sortedDoc.map((item) => {
      item.comments.isReady = true;
      return item;
    });

    res.send(modifiedDocs);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Get Data Error' + err);
  }
};
```

Comment: is there any way to add it with mongo db Query Modifiers ¶

Comment: Do you mean like using Mongoose? That might make changes to the doc in the DB? @DimerBwimba

Comment: I mean like db.collection.find( { <query> } )._addSpecial( <option> )

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Are you getting this `db.collection.find( { <query> } )._addSpecial( <option> )` from Mongoose documentation? @DimerBwimba

Comment: I think you probably mean to use [Mongoose Lean](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean)

Comment: yes , And modifiers https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-modifier/

Comment: I just modified my suggestion. Let me know what errors you get or if you have any questions/clarification? @DimerBwimba

Comment: (node:19876) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseError: Operation `posts.find()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous>

Comment: Could you try without the `doc.sort()`?  Also do a `console.log(doc)` I wanna see what `doc` returns